# Random freezing on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I have been having this problem for a while now, although it doesn't happen that often. What happens is that, sometimes, even while idle my PC just freezes. If sound is playing, it continues for a little and then this horrendous sound start playing. I have reinstalled windows.

I don't think it's the graphics card, since it happens even while doing light tasks. I updated my drivers recently, but it didn't fix it. There isn't a specific moment that it started happening.

Hardware:

```
AMD Ryzen 2200G
Gigabyte RX 570 4GB
Samsung EVO 860 250GB
HyperX 2666 MHz 8GB memory
ASRock ab350m motherboard
Corsair 450 watt psu
```

I have tried reinstalling windows, no results. Driver updates didn't do anything either. PSU did work correctly for half a year now, maybe it's starting to fail? Haven't done any hardware upgrades recently. I am planning to get a new graphics card.

Any ideas? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to find useful messages in the Event Viewer.

Comment: It just crashed, Only error in the last minute or so was event 41, Kernel-Power:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

Comment: See if [BlueScreenView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) shows crash info.

Comment: It doesn't show anything at this point in time, I could leave it on until it crashes but I don't think it'll show anything.

Comment: It's not a Windows crash, then. If I needed to guess, I would most likely point to the video driver (load is not a factor). Download your driver [from here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx). How much RAM does the video card have (see [link](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2018/07/09/buyer-beware-nvidias-geforce-gt-1030-is-a-grossly-misleading-gpu/))?

Comment: I installed the most recent drivers using the link, my graphics card has 2GB of vram.

Comment: I think your problem is similar to one I once had. The only solution was to change the computer, and I did search the issue.

Comment: It just chrashed again on new hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never managed to find the issue, but it seems to be the pci slot that was malfunctioning. I replaced the motherboard and never had an issue again.

Answer (score 1):

I had random freezes with my Ryzen CPU as well. 2700X and Vega 56 GPU. If you are experiencing issues with some Games with Launchers or Google Chrome not working also, then the problem is caused by Cryptsvc.dll. Took me a whole lot of time to figure it out after freezes didn't go away, even with a fresh Win10 install.

To find out if this is the issue, create a bat-file on your desktop with the following content:
SC Stop CryptSvc

save it as Crypt.bat and run it as administrator. If this fixes the crashes for a while (service will restart itself), you can go ahead and do the following:

Set the Cryptographic Services under Windows Services to run locally. Right click on preferences of the service, set it to run in local mode and save it. After this, go to registry (regedit in command prompt) and set the value "EnableLUA" in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" to "0".

That's it. Will mess a bit with your windows User Account Control, but it's the only possible fix, except you want to keep the batch-file solution as permanent solution.